# How to properly use boxes or grid in gtkmm3

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtk, gtkmm3

I am desperately trying to create a simple GUI using gtkmm3 on the raspberry pi and have been struggling with this for too long. However, when I run the program, I seem to get a segmentation fault and I have no idea why..If I take out the last row on the grid, it works. Is there something I am doing a wrong or a better approach?

Here's the header file, gui_ex.h:

```
#ifndef GTKMM_EX_GUI_H
#define GTKMM_EX_GUI_H

#include <gtkmm.h>

class Gui_Ex : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    Gui_Ex();
    virtual ~Gui_Ex();

protected:
    // Signal handlers:
    void on_connect_click();  
    void on_quit();


    //child widgets
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Adjustment> m_adjustment;
  Gtk::Box m_VBox;
  Gtk::Label m_label, m_label2, m_label3;
  Gtk::Grid m_grid;
  Gtk::SpinButton m_spin;
  Gtk::Button m_button3, m_button4;//, m_connect;


};

#endif // GTKMM_EX_GUI_H
```

gui_ex.cpp:

```
#include "gui_ex.h"
Gui_Ex::Gui_Ex()
:
   m_adjustment( Gtk::Adjustment::create(1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 1.0, 5.0, 0.0) ),
   m_VBox(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL), 

   m_label2("label2"),
   m_label3("label3"),
   m_button3("Connect"),
   m_button4("Quit"),
   m_spin(m_adjustment),  
   m_label("Choose the number of clients")  
{
    set_title("Grid");
  set_border_width(16);

  add(m_VBox);


  m_VBox.pack_start(m_grid);
  m_grid.attach(m_label, 0,0,2,1); //column, row, width (# col span), height (# row span). starts at 0
  m_grid.attach(m_spin, 2,0,1,1);
  m_grid.attach(m_label2, 0,1,2,1);
  m_grid.attach(m_label3, 2,1,1,1);
  m_grid.attach(m_button3, 0,2,2,1);
  m_grid.attach(m_button4, 2,2,1,1);

  m_spin.set_wrap();
  m_spin.set_numeric(true);

  m_button3.set_sensitive(true);
  m_button4.set_sensitive(false);  

  m_button3.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &Gui_Ex::on_connect_click));
  m_button4.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &Gui_Ex::on_quit));  


  show_all_children();

}

Gui_Ex::~Gui_Ex()
{
}

void Gui_Ex::on_quit(){
  bool running = false;
  m_spin.set_sensitive(true);

 m_button3.set_sensitive(true);

}


void Gui_Ex::on_connect_click()
{
    int BACKLOG = m_spin.get_value_as_int();
    m_spin.set_sensitive(false);
    m_button4.set_sensitive(true);
}
```

main_gui_ex.cpp:

```
#include "gui_ex.h"
#include <gtkmm/application.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");

    Gui_Ex gui_ex;

    return app ->run(gui_ex);

}
```

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the code. Can you run the program in a debugger and show a stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workaround solution. The original code still doesn't work for reasons I still don't know. Below is the backtrace of that in GDB.

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/pi/cplus/gui_ex
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".

** (gui_ex:741): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb6b4d7b4 in Gio::Application::signal_activate() ()
   from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgiomm-2.4.so.1
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0xb6b4d7b4 in Gio::Application::signal_activate() ()
   from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgiomm-2.4.so.1
#1  0xb6e189cc in Gtk::Application::run(Gtk::Window&) ()
   from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgtkmm-3.0.so.1
#2  0x00014504 in main ()
(gdb)
```

For my solution, I created the UI in Glade and imported it into my program using the Gtk::Builder.

Here is the code:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Gtk::SpinButton *spinbutton1 = 0;
Gtk::RadioButton *m_rby, *m_rbn = 0;
Gtk::Button *button_stop, *button_start = 0;

void buttonstart_clicked()
{


  cout << spinbutton1->get_value_as_int() << endl;

  button_start->set_sensitive(false);
  button_stop->set_sensitive(true);
}
void buttonstop_clicked()
{



  button_start->set_sensitive(true);
  button_stop->set_sensitive(false);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");

  //Load the GtkBuilder file and instantiate its widgets:
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> refBuilder = Gtk::Builder::create();
  try
  {
    refBuilder->add_from_file("simplegui.glade");
  }
  catch(const Glib::FileError& ex)
  {
    std::cerr << "FileError: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  catch(const Glib::MarkupError& ex)
  {
    std::cerr << "MarkupError: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  catch(const Gtk::BuilderError& ex)
  {
    std::cerr << "BuilderError: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }



  Gtk::Window *window1 = 0;

  refBuilder->get_widget("window1", window1); 
  refBuilder->get_widget("button_stop", button_stop);
  refBuilder->get_widget("button_start", button_start);
  refBuilder->get_widget("spinbutton1", spinbutton1);

  refBuilder->get_widget("radiobutton1", m_rby);
  refBuilder->get_widget("radiobutton2", m_rbn);

  Gtk::RadioButton::Group group = m_rby->get_group();
  m_rbn->set_group(group);
  m_rby->set_active();

  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Adjustment> m_adjustment = Gtk::Adjustment::create(1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 1.0, 5.0, 0.0);
  spinbutton1->set_adjustment(m_adjustment);

  // connect more signals
  button_start->signal_clicked().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(buttonstart_clicked));
  button_stop->signal_clicked().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(buttonstop_clicked));




  app->run(*window1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your original `main()` function from the code that didn't work?

Comment: I edited the original question and posted the main().

Comment: So it's not a lifetime issue. Huh. I don't know enough about gtkmm to know the answer then, sorry. (I do know about GTK+, but again, I don't see anything wrong on that level...)

Comment: Thanks anyway! I'm just glad I found a workaround, and it's a lot easier to implement anyhow.